# prevent inheritance of derived class using protected c++

Tags: c++, inheritance

```
class A
{
    //friend class B;
    protected:
    A(){cout << "A\n";};

};
class B:  virtual A
{};

class C :  B
{};

int main() {
 C c;
 return 0;
}
```

I am able to compile this code successfully though I was expecting error due to A:A() is protected.
Basing on the fact that for virtual base class its most derived class calls it base class directly.
The above code gives compile error[expected] for private access to ctor() in base class.
Can someone please clarify this, Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to forbid inheritance from `A` ?

Comment: I want to forbid inheritance from B.

Answer (score 3):

Having a `protected` access specifier means that derived classed may access the entity. `C` is also derived from `A`, it doesn't have to be directly derived from it to qualify for protected access.

On the other hand, `private` access will prevent any derived class from having accessibility, both `B` *and* `C`.

There is no way to control access in a way that will only allow directly derived classed to access the constructor (specifically, an open set of directly derived classes). The most you can do is to play with `private` access and `friend`ship with a closed set of derived classes.

---

To address your comment on your question:

> I want to forbid inheritance from B

Just mark `B` as final

```
class B final : A
{};
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

Comment: @knils - I can't, since (a) you posted it in a comment, making it unreadable (b) it's an entirely different question that has nothing to do with the one just answered. (c) This is not a forum or a board, this is a Q&A site. If you have a followup question, you post it as a separate question, so it can be properly answered, and not just buried in a comment.

Comment: Please revoke my ban from asking questions in this community.Thanks!

Comment: @knils - uh? I have no power to either ban or unban you. The system does it automatically if you produce too many questions that are deemed of a low quality. You can read about it, as well as about how to resolve it, [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)